# How to remove decimal points in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, df, which looks like this:

```
Cut-off             <=35   >35                   
Calcium              0.0   1.0
Copper               1.0   0.0
Helium               0.0   8.0
Hydrogen             0.0   1.0
```

How can I remove the decimal point so that the data frame looks like this:

```
Cut-off             <= 35  > 35                   
Calcium              0     1
Copper               1     0
Helium               0     8
Hydrogen             0     1
```

I have tried `df.round(0)` without success.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have a few options...

1) convert everything to integers.

```
df.astype(int)
          <=35  >35
Cut-off            
Calcium      0    1
Copper       1    0
Helium       0    8
Hydrogen     0    1
```

2) Use `round`:

```
>>> df.round()
          <=35  >35
Cut-off            
Calcium      0    1
Copper       1    0
Helium       0    8
Hydrogen     0    1
```

but not always great...

```
>>> (df - .2).round()
          <=35  >35
Cut-off            
Calcium     -0    1
Copper       1   -0
Helium      -0    8
Hydrogen    -0    1
```

3) Change your display precision option in Pandas.

```
pd.set_option('precision', 0)

>>> df
          <=35  >35
Cut-off            
Calcium      0    1
Copper       1    0
Helium       0    8
Hydrogen     0    1
```

Comment: @alexander how would one apply any of these methods to one particular column? Would it be? `df[">35"].round()`

Comment: @3kstc Yes.  Probably best to convert result to integer `df[">35"].round().astype(int)`

Comment: For your last comment. Why do you need `round()` if you will use `astype(int)` anyway? And why does `round()` give me one decimal place even if I leave it as blank or put zero in? Thanks

Comment: `astype(int)` truncates the value, so `pd.Series([.9]).astype(int)` results in a value of zero.  It would be one if you first rounded.

Answer (score 22):

Since pandas 0.17.1 you can set the displayed numerical precision by [modifying the style of the particular data frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) rather than setting the global option:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df
```

[image]

```
df.style.set_precision(2)
```

[image]

It is also possible to apply column specific styles

```
df.style.format({
    'A': '{:,.1f}'.format,
    'B': '{:,.3f}'.format,
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use this code as well if you do not want decimals at all:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0',''))
```

Comment: This will incorrectly transform values like 0.01 to 01

Comment: It will also convert your column to string, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: To avoid the incorrect result quoted by @DiegoFMedina, I use the regex, like this: df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: re.sub( r'\.0$', '', x) )

Comment: This is good if your column might have `nan` or `inf` in (and you never have values like 1.01 as Diego points out - typically a database extract with an optional foreign key).