# Printing Numpy arrays without brackets

Tags: python, numpy

```
predictions  = [x6,x5,x4,x3,x2,x1]
predictions
```

Calling the above list yields the following arrays:

```
[array([782.36739152]),
 array([783.31415872]),
 array([726.90474426]),
 array([772.08910103]),
 array([728.79734162]),
 array([753.67887657])]
```

Yet I would like to print or call just the numbers inside, no array or brackets around the numbers.

Using the function below cleanly saves just the numbers to CSV, but I DON'T want to save the numbers, I want to call them inside iPython:

```
np.savetxt("P:/Earnest/Old/R/OutputPython.csv", predictions, delimiter=",")
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: May be `results = [i[0] for i in predictions]
`

Comment: thanks @student - but writing a for loop just to print a list of numbers seems excessive to after all...just print a list of numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change `predictions` to `numpy` array then, you can use `print(*predictions.flatten(), sep=', ')`.

You can try as following:

```
import numpy as np

predictions = np.array([np.array([782.36739152]),
                        np.array([783.31415872]),
                        np.array([726.90474426]),
                        np.array([772.08910103]),
                        np.array([728.79734162]),
                        np.array([753.67887657])])


print(*predictions.flatten(), sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
782.36739152, 783.31415872, 726.90474426, 772.08910103, 728.79734162, 753.67887657
```

Comment: Or perhaps `predictions = np.concatenate(...)` and avoid having to flatten it. Still, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The result would be a string.

```
>>> ' '.join(str(x[0]) for x in predicitons)
'782.36739152 783.31415872 726.90474426 772.08910103 728.79734162 753.67887657'
```

You could also round the result, e.g. `str(round(x[0], 2))`.

Comment: thanks @Alexander - this is indeed correct.  I'm just a bit surprised that Python/numpy doesn't have an easier way to output a list of numbers in a console.

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084812/how-to-remove-decimal-points-in-pandas/37084889#37084889

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(' '.join(str(i.tolist()[0]) for i in arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Numpy` arrays almost always come with the brackets. If you do not want brackets around each number, but good with them being around the whole array, the following code might help:

```
', '.join([str(lst[0]) for lst in predictions])
```

The delimiter could be modified to suit your purpose.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @U9-Forward I may concede about the inefficiency, because there must be better ways to achieve the same result. But I tested it locally with the sample data provided and it worked on my machine. Could you please help make clear why it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok accepted answers output is: `782.36739152, 783.31415872, 726.90474426, 772.08910103, 728.79734162, 753.67887657` so means that not right output for yours

Comment: @U9-Forward Thank you very much for pointing this out! I will try to modify my solution so as it can really help to some extent :-)

Comment: Ok edit, is better, sorry i can't undownvote, because i didn't downvote

Comment: @U9-Forward No big deal, it is nice to learn from your comments :-)