# Printing a pandas dataframe without row number/index

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following code:

```
predictions  = pd.DataFrame([x6,x5,x4,x3,x2,x1])
print(predictions)
```

Prints the following in the console:

```
            0
0  782.367392
1  783.314159
2  726.904744
3  772.089101
4  728.797342
5  753.678877
```

How do I print `predictions` without row (0-5) or column (0) indexes?

In R the code would look like:

```
print(predictions, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: You can simply use as `print(predictions.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: @student has the right answer

Comment: You nailed it @student

Comment: And I thought Python syntax was simpler than R :)

Comment: Great it worked! I did not add answer since it was already answered. `Happy Coding`. :)

Answer (score 16):

```
print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Comment: That looks nice. You could also do some rounding before printing, e.g. `df.round(2).to_string(...)`

Answer (score 4):

```
print(predictions.values.tolist())
```

Or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

>>> for row in df.values: print(row)
[-1.09989127 -0.17242821 -0.87785842]
[ 0.04221375  0.58281521 -1.10061918]
[ 1.14472371  0.90159072  0.50249434]
[ 0.90085595 -0.68372786 -0.12289023]
[-0.93576943 -0.26788808  0.53035547]
```

Comment: That returns: [[782.3673915172626], [783.314158724909], [726.9047442598429], [772.0891010290351], [728.7973416236138], [753.67887656913]]  - I'm not looking to return brackets or commas, just numbers

Comment: I just answered this related question about 10 mins ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396315/printing-numpy-arrays-without-brackets

Answer (score 2):

Or use:

```
predictions[0].tolist()
```

Or can do something like:

```
'\n'.join(map(str,predictions[0].tolist()))
```

Or can do:

```
for i in str(df).splitlines()[1:]:
    print(i.split(None,1)[1])
```

Or want to assign to string:

```
s=''
for i in str(df).splitlines()[1:]:
    s+=i.split(None,1)[1]+'\n'
print(s.rstrip())
```

Comment: This still has commas, anyway to just simply print the numbers in the dataframe?

Comment: @ZJAY Then do, `'\n'.join(map(str,predictions[0].tolist()))`