# How to drop values ending with .0 from column with two different dtypes in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read my csv in Python where I read "col1" as str dtype.

Nevertheless, I have different dtypes in this column (float and string) as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5de.png)

What can I do so as to drop obserwations where in col1 I have values ending with .0 or simply drop float values from this column ? I totally do not know ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that col1 is an actual value in your dataset, perhaps you did not set it as a Title of your column. About having different types such as integer and float in your dataset you might look at this thread to see how you can convert all of them into just integers [How to remove decimal points in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084812/how-to-remove-decimal-points-in-pandas).