# How can I remove the .0 after floats in a DataFrame without changing the object type? (I have NANs and require numerical sorting)

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to remove the .0s after `floats` in a column of a `DataFrame`, made from a `dictionary`.

For example, the `dictionary` might be:

`mydict = {   "part1" : [1,2,None,4,5]   "part2" : [6,7,None,9,10] }`

and then when I `mydf = pd.DataFrame(mydict)`, the `DataFrame` generated is as follows:

`part1    part2`
`0     1.0      6.0`
`1     2.0      7.0`
`2     NaN      NaN`
`3     4.0      9.0`
`4     5.0     10.0`

This happens because every single column in a `DataFrame` must have all objects of the same type. But, I want to have no .0s at the end of my data for look purposes. Obviously, I can't make them integers, due to the lack of an `NaN` in integers. I also can't make them strings, for the reason of numerical sorting. I also wouldn't want `"01","02","03"…"10"` for the purpose of looks.

Becuase this project is really serious, the looks matter, so please don't blame me of overthinking looks of data.

Comment: You can find this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas

Comment: Would `pd.set_option('precision', 0)` work for you? See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084812/how-to-remove-decimal-points-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

the comments point out a couple of solutions.

- i prefer to cast to type `.astype('Int64')` which retains the `NaN` as a `<NA>`.

here is my solution (with your data):

```py
import pandas as pd

mydict = {"part1":[1,2,None,4,5],  "part2":[6,7,None,9,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)


df['part2'] = df['part2'].astype('Int64')
print(df)
```

returns this:

```
   part1  part2
0    1.0      6
1    2.0      7
2    NaN   <NA>
3    4.0      9
4    5.0     10
```

You can apply the above to one (or many) columns of your choice.